# updating SQL database and ArrayList<> using custom adapter.

Tags: java, android, arraylist, adapter

i am using Switch button in mainactivity and using CustonAdapter for populating the data. What i want is when i turn off my switch button data should change form my SQLdatabase as well as from custom arraylist since i am using arraylist in custom adapter for data handling.
here is my custom adapter code

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    int position = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
    Object object = getItem(position);
    DataModel dataModel = (DataModel) object;
    Context context  = buttonView.getContext();

    if (isChecked){
        MessageDbHelper mDbHelper = new MessageDbHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MessageEntry.COLUMN_STATUS_CHECK, MessageEntry.DAY_ON);
        db.update(MessageEntry.TABLE_NAME,values,MessageEntry._ID + "=?",new String[]
                {String.valueOf(buttonView.getTag())});
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        MessageDbHelper mDbHelper = new MessageDbHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MessageEntry.COLUMN_STATUS_CHECK, MessageEntry.DAY_OFF);
        db.update(MessageEntry.TABLE_NAME,values,MessageEntry._ID + "=?",new String[]
                {String.valueOf(buttonView.getTag())});
        remove(dataModel); // here i was trying to change datamodel also remove is just for checking but not working
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtName;
    TextView txtTime;
    TextView txtRepeat;
    Switch msgSwitch;
}

public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<DataModel> data, Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.fields, data);
    this.dataSet = data;
    this.mContext = context;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    DataModel dataModel = getItem(position);

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    final View result;

    if (convertView == null) {

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fields, parent, false);
        viewHolder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        viewHolder.txtTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
        viewHolder.txtRepeat = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.repeat);
        viewHolder.msgSwitch = (Switch) convertView.findViewById(R.id.MessageSwitch);

        result = convertView;

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        result = convertView;
    }

    viewHolder.txtName.setText(dataModel.getPersonName());
    viewHolder.txtTime.setText(dataModel.getTime());
    viewHolder.txtRepeat.setText(dataModel.getRepeat());
    viewHolder.msgSwitch.setChecked(dataModel.getStatus());


    return convertView;
}
```

and this is my datamodel arraylist

```
public class DataModel implements Serializable{
String name;
String time;
String repeat;
boolean check;

public DataModel(String name, String time, String repeat, boolean check) {
    this.name = name;
    this.time = time;
    this.repeat = repeat;
    this.check = check;
}

public String getPersonName() {
    return name;
}
public String getTime() {
    return time;
}
public String getRepeat() {
    return repeat;
}
public boolean getStatus() {
    return check;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/365979/How-to-update-array-adapter-dynamically-and-update
look at this site , maybe solve your problem

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Link-only answers are usually discouraged at stackoverflow, and this answer is likely to be deleted soon. Maybe you can extend your answer in a way that it is still helpful without the link.